# TLS Server Hello message has incorrect Certificate information

Tags: ssl, certificate

I am using a self-signed certificate for my forest created by Microsoft CA. All DC's are auto-enrolled and receive the correct certificate from the CA and LDAPS connections can be established using LDP.
However, on the DC that hosts the CA LDP is unable to establish a TLS connection and the event log reports that the "The certificate received from the remote server was issued by an untrusted certificate authority."

Using "openssl s_client -connect server:636" I receive:
subject=CN = ILLINOIS-DC1A.DOMAIN.COM
issuer=CN = ILLINOIS-DC1A.DOMAIN.COM

Whereas on a working server I receive:
subject=
issuer=DC = com, DC = domain, CN = illinois-ILLINOIS-DC1A-CA

Inspecting the two certificates in the Certificate Store shows that both have the correct Issuer data.

So, why does ADDS strip the DC fields when creating the Server Hello data on the failing server?

Comment: _"I am using a self-signed certificate for my forest created by Microsoft CA."_ - would you care to elaborate?  A Microsoft CA is normally used to create (oddly enough) a CA, which then issues certificates to subscribers (such as DCs).  If you've got a CA issued certificate you would expect the issuer and subject to differ.  Is this a case of the DC not having a LDAPS cert issued by the CA and using an internally generated, self-signed one instead?

Comment: I just meant that when I installed the CA as a Root CA I also created a new private key.
All the certificates have been created by the CA. I used Group Policy to distribute the Certificate (without private key).

Comment: *" why does ADDS strip the DC fields when creating the Server Hello"* - there is no way to strip any information from a certificate without invalidating the signature of the certificate. So this is a different certificate you are looking at, not the original one with stripped information.

Comment: That was my suspicion, especially after I deleted all the certificates in the Computer/Personal Store and yet ADDS continued to send the malformed certificate in the Server Hello packet. So, where else can a Certificate reside?

Comment: Also: [Never install a certification authority on a domain controller in a production environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/hello-for-business/deploy/on-premises-cert-trust-pki)

Comment: This a dev environment with 4 actual users, 5000 inactive users, one forest, two child domains and 3 grandchild domains.

Answer (score 1):

Solved the issue. There was a rogue Certificate in the Active Directory Domain Services NTDS\Personal container - deleted that and now I can establish an LDAPS connection.